# Props not being used correctly in styled-components div's CSS

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have `Item` components that take an `itemId` and `itemBeingEdited` as props. If these two are equal (i.e. the current Item is indeed the one that is being edited), that Item's border should be 5px solid red. If they are not equal, that Item's border should be 2px solid black. While it looks like the equalities are being correctly evaluated (from console.logs), styled-components is treating them both as though they evaluate to `TRUE`

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-props-border-s9p47

Expected: first div should have a 2px solid black border, second div should have a 5px solid red border.

Actual: both divs have the red border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass props to `<ItemWrapper {...props} />` explicitly.

```
const Item = props => {
  console.log(props.itemId === props.itemBeingEdited);
  return <ItemWrapper {...props} />;
};
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-props-border-0ettv